# audio is out of sync after concat 2 files

Tags: ffmpeg

i want to show a video, that has 2 movies side by side. each movie is a result of one movie that concat 2 times. the problem is that the audio in the right side is out of sync.

**i have 3 commands:**
first command concat one movie 2 times

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 1.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[concatv][concata]" -map "[concatv]" -map "[concata]" Concat1.mp4
```

second command concat the second movie 2 times

```
ffmpeg -i 2.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[concatv][concata]" -map "[concatv]" -map "[concata]" Concat2.mp4
```

at this point the audio is always synced.
the third command takes the 2 results and merge it to one movie side by side with a logo:

```
ffmpeg -i Concat1.mp4 -i Concat2.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v]pad=width=iw+20:height=ih+20:x=10:y=10:color=black[a];[1:v]pad=width=iw+20:height=ih+20:x=10:y=10:color=black[b];nullsrc=size=640x480[base];[a]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x480[left];[b]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x480[right];[base][left]overlay=shortest=1[tmp1];[tmp1][right] overlay=320:0[video];[0:a]apad [apa];[apa][1:a]amerge=inputs=2,pan=stereo|FL<c0+c1|FR<c0+c1[audio];[2:v]scale=120:44 [ovrl];[video][ovrl]overlay=15:25[videoandlogo]" -map "[videoandlogo]" -map "[audio]" output.mp4
```

the problem is that in **the output file the audio of the right movie is out of sync** in its second time (the second concat). it always the right movie that is out of sync, even when i switch them.

can anyone help?
Thanks.

**==============EDIT===================**

the problem of the sync **has solved** by adding apad also to the second file, **but after that the command never stops**... how can i tell the command to stop when both movies ended if i have apad for both movies?
this is the new command that never stops:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -i 2.mp4 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[0:v]pad=width=iw+20:height=ih+20:x=10:y=10:color=black[a];[1:v]pad=width=iw+20:height=ih+20:x=10:y=10:color=black[b];nullsrc=size=640x480[base];[a]scale=320x480[left];[b]scale=320x480[right];[base][left]overlay=shortest=1[tmp1];[tmp1][right] overlay=320:0[video];[1:a]apad [apa];[0:a]apad[apa1];[apa][apa1]amix=inputs=2:duration=longest[audio];[2:v]scale=120:44 [ovrl];[video][ovrl]overlay=15:25[videoandlogo]" -map "[videoandlogo]" -map "[audio]" output.mp4
```

Comment: Remove the setpts filters and check.

Comment: Hi, thanks but it still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer (hope it will help someone).
for the audio problem, i solved it by putting apad to all of the movies (need to put the apad of the longest movie first). and to fix the never ending movie i put "-t ".
Thanks.